# How to clone a repository from bit bucket as dependency in package.json, build and package it

Tags: angular, npm

I have a main project with many dependencies, some of which are directly installed from `npm` and couple of them are to be cloned and built from bit bucket as libraries. At present, I clone/pull them individually and then run build and package command and then update the path of the built package `(.tgz)` on my local in the main `package.json` file. I am unsure as I could I simply achieve that whenever I run npm install on the main `package.json`, it automatically downloads the required child repositories, build and packages them.

Following is my main `package.json` -

```
{
  "name": "main",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-n-watch": "ng build --watch"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    .
    .
    .
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "admin": "file:C:/Users/some-project-path/dist/prj1/prj1-0.0.1.tgz",
    "teacher": "file:C:/Users/some-project-path/dist/prj2/prj2-0.0.1.tgz",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Following is my child repository `package.json` that I need to clone, build and pack -

```
{
  "name": "admission",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-n-watch": "ng build --watch",
    "build-n-pack": "npm run build & cd dist/prj1 & npm pack"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    .
    .
    .
```

Following is my bitbucket url where child repositories reside -

```
https://bitbucket.org/team-a/prj1/src/master/
```

I basically need to `clone/pull` from this url, `pm install` and `npm run build-n-pack` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if I was in your shoes i would go for some custom script.js file like the following one

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

function execPull () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const commandExecuter = spawn('git', ['pull'])
    let stdOutData = ''
    let stderrData = ''

    commandExecuter.stdout.on('data', data => (stdOutData += data))
    commandExecuter.stderr.on('data', data => (stderrData += data))
    commandExecuter.on('close', code => {
      console.log('Pull complete')
      return code != 0
        ? reject(stderrData.toString())
        : resolve(stdOutData.toString())
    })
  })
}

function execNpmInstall () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const commandExecuter = spawn('npm.cmd', ['install'])

    let stdOutData = ''
    let stderrData = ''

    commandExecuter.stdout.on('data', data => (stdOutData += data))
    commandExecuter.stderr.on('data', data => (stderrData += data))
    commandExecuter.on('close', code => {
      console.log('Node modules installed')
      return code != 0
        ? reject(stderrData.toString())
        : resolve(stdOutData.toString())
    })
  })
}

execPull()
  .then(() => execNpmInstall())
  .catch(e => {
    throw new Error(e)
  })
```

In the same manner you can chain as many npm commands in the chain.

After that if you want you can create a custom script that you can run with `npm run {your script name}`

```js
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
     ...,
    "{your script command}": "node {your script name}.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

You can check out this npm package [run-git-command](https://github.com/pankajladhar/run-git-command) for running git commands.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Християн Христов . I will definitely give it a try and keep you posted. I was just assuming if there was some easy and built in way as it looked like a common requirement to me. Probably there isn't.